# Reading body of Slack event using python-slackclient

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to create a serverless slack bot in AWS Lambda. I managed to get the app to send a message to a user in Slack with an interactive button, which sends a post back to the app when clicked. The problem is that the body of this message (the one from the button click) has the body of the JSON all garbled. Here is a reduced version of the garble:

'body': 'cGF5bG9hZD0lN0IlMjJ0eXBlJTIyJTNBJTIyYmxvY2tfYWN0aW9...

The rest of the JSON object looks normal.

On the other hand, the button object I'm sending to slack is this one:

```
{
  "type": "button",
  "text": {
    "type": "plain_text",
    "emoji": True,
    "text": "Yes"
  },
   "style": "primary",
  "value": "click_me_123"
},
```

What am I missing? Appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: I guess you are receiving raw body, have you tried using some third party api endpoints like pipedream to get response, I might give you a clear picture how your data is recieved, or try to log the request you are getting as callback

Comment: Hey, thank you! It was that the body was encoded in Base64, so I had to decode that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: It was that the body of the response, it was encoded in Base64, so I had to decode that with:

```
base64.b64decode('encoded_string').decode('utf-8')
```